# Pagination click event executes only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, pagination

I have an ajax pagination enabled Webgrid, So  basically in that webgrid i have checkboxes in the last column, whenever user selects any checkbox and tries to navigate to second page using pagination link, i am calling a click function on pagination link to warn the user that if you navigate to next page your checkbox selection will be lost.
but the problem is that click function executes only once after that it does not execute.
Here is my webgrid code:

```
<div id="gridDiv">
        @{
            var grid = new WebGrid(Model, rowsPerPage: 5, canPage: true, canSort: true, ajaxUpdateContainerId: "gridDiv");
            @grid.GetHtml();
        }
 </div>
```

and pagination click function code

```
 $("table tr a").on('click', function () {
    if (confirm("Your checkbox selection will be lost. Do you want to continue?"))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
})
```

So when the page loads for the first time it warn the user but second time this click function not executing.
Even i placed a debugger also, in that case also i am only able to debug it for one time.
please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

The way that you have your events being registered, jQuery is checking the page for elements that match your selector (`table tr a`) and adding your function to the click event for those elements.  When you paginate, those elements are being removed from the DOM and replaced with new ones and your code is not being run again to register event handlers on those new elements.

So that you don't have to worry about rerunning this code whenever the DOM changes (which can lead to event handlers being added twice or more times).  You can use [$(document).on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) which will take advantage of event bubbling to use the correct event based on the element that was clicked.

You code would become:

```
$('body').on('click', "table tr a", function () {
    if (confirm("Your checkbox selection will be lost. Do you want to continue?"))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
})
```

The listener is now on the document and any elements that get added will have the event triggered.

Comment: hi Schleis, i tried this code but it is not even executing one time.

Comment: your code is not able find the anchor tag in table tr. i have changed that selector to "table tfoot tr td a" then also it is not able to find the anchor tag. But Just for testing i created one anchor tag outside the table and changed the selector to "a" then it is able to find this anchor but not in table. Please help @Schleis

Comment: Try changing the element to the 'body' tag.  That might help.

Answer (score 0):

I did try that also, but still not working. As @Schleis said javascript loses the event binding after dynamically added content, i am rebinding that event on AjaxStop function and it is working fine.

code:-

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
            $("#loader").show();
        }).ajaxStop(function () {
            $("#loader").hide();
            conf();
        })
       // var a = setInterval(conf, 2000);  

        conf();
    })


    function conf()
    {
        $("table tr a").click(function () {
            if (confirm("Your checkbox selection will be lost. Do you want to continue?"))
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        })
       //        alert("hi");
    }
```